# Does dataview in extjs 5.0.1 has prepareData function?

Tags: extjs

I use **ExtJS 5.0.1** and sencha architect 3.

There is a problem bothering me now. A `dataview` some of whose filenames are too long and the pics are in a mess.

I want use prepareData to shorten the name, but could not find it in architect.

Is it deprecated? And is there a alternative function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Architect doesn't support all features and it has a lot of limitations.

Follow these steps to customize your prepareData.

1 - In your project inspector, click on your Data View

2 - In your config panel, select "Process Config" and click on the + sign next to it.

3 - A process method will be created, click on this method and go to the code editor

4 - add this to the code editor

```
return Ext.apply(config, {
    prepareData : function ( data, recordIndex, record ) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

This should customize your prepareData method.

Comment: Would you please to see my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868513/sencha-architect-i-have-a-form-and-how-to-config-its-reader,  It suffered me this afternoon. Thanks a lot.