# Sencha architect, I have a form and how to config its `reader`?

Tags: extjs

Sencha architect,  I have a form and I want to config its `reader` like this,

```
   Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonReader', {
       root : "rows", 
       model : 'city'
   })
```

In Sencha architect, it will be add a pair of single quote mark. So how to config `reader` of the `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ron,

The Form Panel has a reader config that is set to be an object. Edit that object and add the code bellow to it:

```
{
   type : 'json',
   root : 'rows', // if ExtJS 5, this should be rootProperty: 'rows'
   model : 'city'
}
```

Shoud look something like this after you do it.

[image: FormPanel with Custom Reader]

Comment: when I add `{root:'rows,model:'city'}`, I will get Error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` on Chrome. It will disappear once I delete the `reader`.What's the problem?

Comment: When you specify a form reader you also have to add the type, I've updated my example. Also, notice that if you are using ExtJS 5, the config is rootProperty and not root.

Comment: All is PERFECT except architect's Log window shows message `Framework Error: No such Entity "city"` which makes Design view empty.I am very appreciating for your help.

Comment: You should use a model named properly, like 'MyApp.model.City'. Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oru

Comment: Your approach works.Trouble is in architect. When you try to modify something, form wouldn't be showed out. http://i1153.photobucket.com/albums/p515/tongwawa/20150618125555_1.png http://i1153.photobucket.com/albums/p515/tongwawa/20150618125546_2.png http://i1153.photobucket.com/albums/p515/tongwawa/20150618125537_2.png

Comment: Please, report this as a bug in the Sencha Architect Forum. https://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?119-Sencha-Architect-3.x-Bugs&s=cb4b3d0781f301e4b6c296391b68186b

Comment: OK,  Guilherme. It's my pleasure.